# How to filter data using between dates and coordinator name?

Tags: php, mysql

I am a newbie of PHP. I am trying to filter data using between dates (date picker) and coordinator name but I am not able to get the correct result. I hope you can help me with this.

index.php

```
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "filter");  
 $query = "
 SELECT * 
   FROM delivery_summary a
       , suppliers b 
   where a.ds_supid = b.sup_serial 
   ORDER 
      BY ds_date
 ";  
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Ajax PHP MySQL Date Range Search using jQuery DatePicker</title>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:900px;">  
                <h2 align="center">Ajax PHP MySQL Date Range Search using jQuery DatePicker</h2>  
                <h3 align="center">Delivery Summary</h3><br />  
                <div class="col-md-3">  
                     <input type="text" name="from_date" id="from_date" class="form-control" placeholder="From Date" />  
                </div>  
                <div class="col-md-3">  
                     <input type="text" name="to_date" id="to_date" class="form-control" placeholder="To Date" />  
                </div>  
                <div class="col-md-5">  
                     <input type="text" name="coord_name" id="coord_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Coordinator" />  
                </div>  
                <div class="col-md-9">  
                     <input type="button" name="filter" id="filter" value="Search" class="btn btn-info" />  
                </div>  
            <td></td>
                </div>  
                <div style="clear:both"></div>                 
                <br />  
                <div id="summary_table">  
                     <table class="table table-bordered">  
                          <tr>  
                               <th width="10%">Last Name</th>  
                               <th width="10%">First Name</th>  
                               <th width="10%">DR Number</th>  
                               <th width="10%">DR Date</th>  
                               <th width="10%">Amount</th>  
                               <th width="10%">Balance</th>
                               <th width="10%">Coordinator</th> 
                          </tr>  
                     <?php  
                     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                     {  
                     ?>  
                          <tr>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["sup_lastname"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["sup_firstname"]; ?></td>
                               <td><?php echo $row["ds_drnumber"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["ds_date"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["ds_amount"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["ds_balance"]; ?></td>  
                               <td><?php echo $row["coordinator"]; ?></td>
                          </tr>  
                     <?php  
                     }  
                     ?>  
                     </table>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
<script>  
      $(document).ready(function(){  
           $.datepicker.setDefaults({  
           dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'   
           });  
           $(function(){  
                $("#from_date").datepicker();  
                $("#to_date").datepicker();  

           });  
           $('#filter').click(function(){  
                var from_date = $('#from_date').val();  
                var to_date = $('#to_date').val();  

                if(from_date != '' && to_date != '')  
                {  
                     $.ajax({  
                          url:"filter_summary.php",  
                          method:"POST",  
                          data:{from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date},  
                          success:function(data)  
                          {  
                               $('#summary_table').html(data);  
                          }  
                     });  
                }  
                else  
                {  
                     alert("Please Select Date");  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 </script>
```

filter_summary.php

```
<?php  
 //filter_summary.php  

 if(isset($_POST["from_date"], $_POST["to_date"], $_POST["coord_name"]))  

 {  

      $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "filter");  
      $output = '';  
      $query = "  
      SELECT * 
        FROM delivery_summary a
           , suppliers b 
       where a.ds_supid = b.sup_serial 
         AND coord_name '".$_POST["coord_name"]."' 
         AND ds_date BETWEEN '".$_POST["from_date"]."' AND '".$_POST["to_date"]."'  
      ";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
      $output .= '  
           <table class="table table-bordered">  
                <tr>  
                     <th width="15%">Last Name</th>  
                     <th width="15%">First Name</th>  
                     <th width="15%">DR Number</th>  
                     <th width="15%">DR Date</th>  
                     <th width="15%">Amount</th>  
                     <th width="15%">Balance</th>
                     <th width="15%">Coordinator</th>                    
                </tr>  
      ';  
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
      {  
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
           {  
                $output .= '  
                     <tr>  
                          <td>'. $row["sup_lastname"] .'</td>  
                          <td>'. $row["sup_firstname"] .'</td>
                          <td>'. $row["ds_drnumber"] .'</td>  
                          <td>'. $row["ds_date"] .'</td>  
                          <td>'. $row["ds_amount"] .'</td>  
                          <td>'. $row["ds_balance"] .'</td>  
                          <td>'. $row["coordinator"] .'</td>
                     </tr>  
                ';  
           }  
      }  
      else  
      {  
           $output .= '  
                <tr>  
                     <td colspan="5">Records Found!!!</td>  
                </tr>  
           ';  
      }  
      $output .= '</table>';  
      echo $output;  
 }  
 ?>
```

Comment: `AND coord_name '".$_POST["coord_name"]."' AND` looks like a syntax error, and a SQL injection hole. Use error reporting, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php. You should use parameterized queries. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: thanks I will check the links...